# WPF DataGrid (Two-Way) Binding of Radio buttons to single property of Object in collection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a data class defined as follows (shortened for brevity):

```
Partial Public Class ClassName
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of MyObject)

    Public Event ItemPropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler

    Private Property _ContainsChanges As Boolean
    Public ReadOnly Property ContainsChanges As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ContainsChanges
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub Notify_PropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String)
        MyBase.OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Notify_ItemPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemPropertyChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Me_PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
        Me._ContainsChanges = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Me_CollectionChanged(Sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.CollectionChanged
        If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add Then
            For Each item As Account In e.NewItems
                AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Account_PropertyChanged
            Next
        ElseIf e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove Then
            For Each item As Account In e.OldItems
                RemoveHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Account_PropertyChanged
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub MyObject_PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Me._ContainsChanges = True
        Notify_ItemPropertyChanged(e)
    End Sub

    Partial Public Class MyObject
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Private Property _ContainsChanges As Boolean
        Public ReadOnly Property ContainsChanges As Boolean
            Get
                Return _ContainsChanges
            End Get
        End Property

        Private Property _IntegerProperty As Integer
        Public Property IntegerProperty As Integer
            Get
                Return _IntegerProperty
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                If value <> _IntegerPropertyThen
                    _IntegerProperty= value
                    Notify_PropertyChanged("IntegerProperty")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Property _BooleanProperty As Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Public Property BooleanProperty As Nullable(Of Boolean)
            Get
                Return _BooleanProperty 
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                If value <> _BooleanProperty  Then
                    _BooleanProperty = value
                    Notify_PropertyChanged("BooleanProperty ")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub Notify_PropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
        End Sub

        Protected Overridable Sub Me_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
            Me._ContainsChanges = True
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

This collection is bound to a WPF User Control with a datagrid as its only element. Each object in the collection is represented by a row in the datagrid. The XAML is shown below:

```
<UserControl 
             x:Class="WPFControlNameSpace.WPFControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WPFControlLibrary.WPFControlNameSpace.Converters"
             DataContext="{Binding DataGrid}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="dgHeaderStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value=".5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="dgStyle">
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Beige" />
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
            <Setter Property="MinColumnWidth" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgClassName" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              ColumnHeaderStyle ="{StaticResource dgHeaderStyle}"
              Style="{StaticResource dgStyle}" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              FontFamily="Arial">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lActive}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="This row is Active!" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lActive}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="This row is Inactive!" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Account Number " Binding="{Binding nAccountNumber}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="50"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Account Description " Binding="{Binding cAccountDescription}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="50"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Verified ">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Content="Yes"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty,
                                                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                                                     ConverterParameter='True', Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <RadioButton Content="No"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty,
                                                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                                                     ConverterParameter='False', Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <RadioButton Content="Unknown"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty,
                                                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                                                     ConverterParameter='Nothing', Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

The convert that I'm using is shown below:

```
Namespace SungardVerification.Converters
    Class BooleanConverter
        Implements IValueConverter
        Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
            Dim SourceValue = CType(value, System.Nullable(Of Boolean))
            Dim RadioButtonCheckedValue As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Nothing

            If DirectCast(parameter, String).ToUpper.Trim() <> "NOTHING" Then
                RadioButtonCheckedValue = Boolean.Parse(DirectCast(parameter, String))
            End If

            If (RadioButtonCheckedValue.HasValue AndAlso SourceValue.HasValue AndAlso RadioButtonCheckedValue.Value = SourceValue.Value) OrElse
                (Not RadioButtonCheckedValue.HasValue AndAlso Not SourceValue.HasValue) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
            Dim RadioButtonChecked = CType(value, Boolean)
            Dim RadioButtonCheckedValue As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Nothing
            Dim SourceValue As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Nothing

            If RadioButtonChecked = True Then
                If DirectCast(parameter, String).ToUpper.Trim() <> "NOTHING" Then
                    SourceValue = Boolean.Parse(DirectCast(parameter, String))
                End If
                Return SourceValue
            Else
                Return Binding.DoNothing
            End If
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This control exists in a User control library, and is included on a windows form using an element host.

The datagrid correctly binds the values from the collection to the cells, however the twoway aspect of this binding is not working correctly.

I know that this could be done with an indeterminate check box, however the radio buttons will be clearer to the user as to the meaning of what they're selecting.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct behavior wasn't being noticed because the UpdateSourceTrigger property was left as the default. Changing the XAML to what's below fixes my issue.

```
<RadioButton Content="Unknown"
             IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty,
                         Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                         ConverterParameter='Nothing', Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```